# noexec flag for /tmp (OpenSUSE)

Tags: security, opensuse, executable, tmp, hardening

I would harden my OpenSUSE 42.2. If I put `noexec` flag for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` locations mount, zypper could suffer for this?

Possible issues could depend by single package working and needing but above all I'm interested about a way for bypass any flag-related error and exploit one possible zypper feature, that I don't know.

I find some things about other package management impact and resolution (apt-get, pacman...) but no one documentation about zypper... I could remount directories whenever could be necessary, but I prefer an absolute and straightforward solution, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the noexec flag on `/tmp` has no real security benefit. If a program is buggy and executes an unvetted program under `/tmp`, it might do so by executing it directly, or by passing it as an argument to an intepreter. If the file is passed as an argument to an interpreter, it doesn't need to be executable.

Setting the noexec flag on `/tmp` is likely to break some programs that expect to be able to write a temporary executable and execute it. The temporary executable could be, for example, a compiled program generated on the fly from some source code or intermediate code, or a cleanup script.